# Get index from jquery array objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I get this array in my chrome console, using this method `$("#gallery_thumbnails .owl-item.active").get();`:

```
Array[5]
0:div.owl-item.active
1:div.owl-item.active.synced
2:div.owl-item.active
3:div.owl-item.active
4:div.owl-item.active
```

[image]

**But I want only the array indexs, like this:**

[image]

How can I get this result?

Comment: How about getting the `length` and creating on your own?

Comment: Doesn't make sense at all to me.

Comment: What value does it have if the index is equal to it's value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over your object array and save keys to new array.

```
var out = [];
for (key in arrays) {
    out.push(key);
}
console.log(out);
```

Or as suggested by other user, use this method:

```
var out = [];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    out.push(i);
}
console.log(out);
```

Comment: `for..in` is meant to loop over object. It will also iterate over other properties like length. These will be skipped in modern browsers

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `map` method from `jQuery`

```
$.map($("#gallery_thumbnails .owl-item.active").get(), function (val, i) {
    return i;
});
```